How to serve a Cloud Run App from an App Engine App on specific route?
We have an application that is currently deployed in Google App Engine. In an effort to upgrade our tech stack and improve our overall infra, we have decided to do the upgrade module-by-module.
One of the improvements we have is to deploy our upgraded (tech stack) modules to Cloud Run.
My question is, in our App Engine application, is it possible that when a user visits the route /posts/v2, the module that is deployed in Cloud Run will be served and be accessed by the users?
I have tried deploying a dispatch.yaml, but I think this only works for App Engine services, and not for Cloud Run apps.

Do you have a loadbalancer in front of App Engine? Is it an option?

dispatch.yaml is only for services running on App Engine. One quick and dirty way to meet your requirements is to do a url redirect from /posts/v2 to the url of your cloud run app. I don't know if that's the most efficient way to solve your problem.
